# Solid State Relay not working, am I mis-reading the data sheet?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I purchased several [IXYS CPC1017NTR SS relays from Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=CPC1017NTRvirtualkey56550000virtualkey849-CPC1017NTR).

I have 1.2v and .5mA of current running over the control input of this relay and the load side isn't connecting.

Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to do roughly (I missed connecting the positive to the load side of the relay in this drawing though)

[image]

I've confirmed with my multimeter the 1.2v/.5mA, so I must have read the datasheet wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Have you tried reducing R1 to 10K ohm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least 1 mA to turn o the optoisolatorn. Your 20k on its own would limit the current to 12/20000 = 0.6 mA which isn't enough. R2 is shunting some of the current that does make it through and stealing it from the SSR.

Try this (and note convention of + rail at top with current flowing from top to bottom of circuit for readability).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX02j3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet says the relay is guaranteed operate with at least 1 mA, and can tolerate up to 50 mA through the LED.  The voltage across the LED when the relay operates may be as much as 1.4 volts.

LEDs are current-operated devices - they will decide what the forward voltage is.  You should always apply a current to an LED, not a fixed voltage.

I would remove R2, and change R1 to 5K1 or less.  That will give the LED about 2 mA, which should reliably operate the relay.

Comment: The also say in a footnote "For applications requiring high temperature operation (greater than 60ºC) a minimum LED drive current of 3mA is recommended."

Comment: I went with a 3.6k resistor since i already had a bunch and it worked perfectly.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

0.4mA and 1.2V are the *typical* values to turn it on. There will be devices for which these do not suffice. Consider exceeding the extreme values instead.

Comment: Max being 1mA and 1.4V.

Comment: Thanks.  So am I reading this right that I can put up to 50mA on the control input?  It just says that typically you'd need .4mA and in all cases 1mA will work?  I can probably just drop the resistor values and easily make that happen.

Comment: @MattMcElroy: Correct. I wouldn't put more than 5mA though, which gives more than enough wiggle room.